# How do I access the string inside my function python?

Tags: python, string, list, function, testing

Trying to gain access  to this string to test it if it has 3 or more blues "b" inside of it. ---Both test and three_or_more_blues are functions.----- I'm completely lost, any one got an idea? Please change my title if it doesn't fit my question. Not sure really how to ask the question. Thanks!

```
test(three_or_more_blues, "brrrrrbrrrrrb")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .count().

```
sentence = 'brrrrrbrrrrrb'
amount = sentence.count('b')
print(amount)
```

And then you could use a loop to calculate your next step.

```
if (amount >= 3): 
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `test` is a function that takes a function and a string as paramters, and `three_or_more_blues` is a function that returns true if its string parameter has 3 or more 'b' characters, then

```
def test(func, str):
    if func(str):
        # do something with str

test(three_or_more_blues, "brrrrrbrrrrrb")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly - you are asking how to pass the string 'brrrrrbrrrrrb' to the `three_or_more_blues` function?

If that is the case, than you just simply pass it when you call the three_or_more_blues function like this:

```
def test(func, some_string):
    func(some_string)  # here you call the passed function

# if three_or_more_blues would look like this:
def three_or_more_blues(some_string):
    print "Yes, 3 or more b's" if some_string.count('b') >= 0 else "No"

# you would get this from your function call
test(three_or_more_blues, "brrrrrbrrrrrb")  # prints: "Yes, 3 or more b's"
```